# Why does setFieldProperty return false?

Tags: c#, fonts, itext

My code sets text into the fields no problem, but when I try to change the font it returns false. I tried some other field properties, like text size with the same result. What am I doing wrong?

```
public string Build()
    {
        Font font = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.COURIER, 8f, Font.BOLD);
        foreach (var i in this.pdfFields)
        {
            bool worked = this.acroFields.SetFieldProperty(i.Name, "textfont", font.BaseFont, null);
            worked = this.acroFields.SetField(i.Name, i.Value);
        }//foreach

        this.pdfStamper.FormFlattening = false;
        this.pdfStamper.Close();

        return this.newFile;
    }//Build
```

**Addendum**

```
    private string templateFile;
    private string newFile;

    private PdfReader pdfReader;
    private PdfStamper pdfStamper;
    private AcroFields acroFields;
    private List<PDFField> pdfFields;

    public PDFer(string templateFile, string newFile)
    {
        this.templateFile = templateFile;
        this.newFile = newFile;

        this.pdfReader = new PdfReader(this.templateFile);
        this.pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(this.newFile, FileMode.Create));
        this.acroFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;

        this.pdfFields = new List<PDFField>();
    }//PDFer

    public void AddTextField(string name, string value)
    {
        this.pdfFields.Add(new PDFTextField(name, value));
    }//AddTextField

    public void AddCheckBox(string name, bool isChecked)
    {
        this.pdfFields.Add(new PDFCheckBox(name, isChecked));
    }//AddCheckBox

    public float getWidth(string s)
    {
        Chunk c = new Chunk(s);
        return c.GetWidthPoint();
    }//getWidth
```

Answer (score 3):

When you set the text size, the value needs to be a `Float` value. If it's an `int`, you're using the wrong method. When you set the font, you need a real `BaseFont` object. I think your `font.BaseFont` is `null`. I'd create the BaseFont like this:

```
BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.COURIER, BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
```

Note that EMBEDDED will be ignored as COURIER is one of the Standard Type 1 fonts.

Comment: I tried this but still get a false. It creates a BaseFont so I changed font to a BaseFont. Also tried just inserting it into the setFieldProperty in place of the font variable.

Comment: I've also tried creating a basefont as you describe, then creating a font from that basefont. Also not successfully.

Comment: I've asked one of our employees to talk a look at it after the weekend. It would help if you send a PDF and a full code sample that reproduces it to support (if you have a license to use iText) or to the mailing-list (if your product is AGPL too).

Comment: Yeah, my boss isn't going to allow that. I appreciate your help, though, and will try to check in to answer questions that arise. I'll append to the original question all the code that has anything to do with iTextSharp. There isn't much.